# Como faço pesquisa (SELECT e WHERE) no firebase database?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase

Tenho um banco de dados assim:

```
{
  "message" : "Hello, World!",
  "reserva" : [ null, {
    "codreserva" : 123,
    "email" : "teste@teste.com",
    "status" : "check in"
  }, {
    "codreserva" : 124,
    "email" : "fabio@ciaf.com.br",
    "status" : "check out"
  } ]
}
```

E tenho um codigo para procurar o  status da reserva:

```
public void ProcuraReserva(String codigodareserva){
// Read from the database
myRef = database.getReference("reserva/"+codigodareserva+"/status");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        textview1.setText("Status da reserva "+ value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        textview1.setText("Status com falha");
    }
  });
}
```

Porem, ele procurar no `ID` da minha reserva queria que ele procurasse de acordo com o `CODRESERVA`. Alguém poderia me ajudar em nessa questão procurar de acordo com a minha "linha" nesse banco de dados do **`Firebase`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar **child()**

[Firebase child](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

```
myRef.child("codreserva").child(codigoreserva).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    textview1.setText("Status da reserva "+ value);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    textview1.setText("Status com falha");
}
```

Comment: Nao trouce nada fazendo isso.

Comment: Acho que o povo nao entendeu dado o codreserva = 123 quero que me retorne o status dela.

Comment: entendi, tente então usar o `equalTo()` para comparar o valor do child. `mCadastroRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...`  o meu funciona assim

Answer (score 0):

O que Fabio nobre falou, ta certo. N esquece q tu tem passar o parametro email que esta dentro de .equalTo. Para receber valores, no teu caso, recomendo que tu faça:

```
  String value = dataSnapshot.child("nome").getValue().toString();
```